# MAGENTO - Remove Item name and price from category grid view

Tags: magento, view, grid

Having trouble figuring this one out. My webpage here: http://www.the-shirt.co.uk/magento (sorry about the loading times. I have not got round to optimizing this yet)

the category product view shows the item picture, the price and a boarder which is far to big!

what i am trying todo is just have a picture. I dont want to display any price, name or boarder. How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon,

I gave an answer for your issue over here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/307687/

I hope this helps!